# PostgreSQL: не правильно обновляет данные в таблице

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет. У меня есть такой запрос:

```
WITH all_values AS (
    SELECT s.projectid AS projectid,
           max(s.prompttype) AS prompttype,
           max(el.inputs->>'name') AS name,
           max(el.inputs->>'desc') AS description,
           v.value AS value,
           max(s.scriptid) AS scriptid,
           max(s.corpuscode) AS corpuscode
    FROM source.table AS s
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs::jsonb) AS el(inputs)
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(el.inputs->'values') AS v(value)
    WHERE
        s.prompttype = 'input' AND (s.created > now() - interval '30 minutes' OR s.modified > now() - interval '30 minutes')
    GROUP BY s.projectid, v.value
   ), not_unique_items AS (
    SELECT all_values.projectid, all_values.prompttype, all_values.name, all_values.description, all_values.value, all_values.scriptid, all_values.corpuscode
    FROM all_values
    WHERE all_values.projectid :: BIGINT IN (SELECT collect_project_id FROM collect.dim_collect_user_inp_configs WHERE collect_project_id IS NOT NULL)
      AND all_values.value :: VARCHAR IN (SELECT prompt_input_value FROM target.table WHERE prompt_input_value IS NOT NULL)
   )
UPDATE target.table
SET prompt_input_desc = s.description, prompt_input_name = s.name, date_updated = NOW()
FROM not_unique_items AS s
WHERE prompt_input_desc != s.description OR prompt_input_name != s.name;
```

Суть этого запроса такова:

1. Сходить в исходную таблицу и взять оттуда данные и разложить JSON на компоненты таким образом, чтобы в одну строку попали уникальные values.
2. Дальше проверить, есть ли такие values в таблице, куда перекладываем данные (то есть выбираем только не уникальные)
3. Если нашли не уникальные, то обновляем некоторые колонки для них и вместе с тем изменяем дату обновления строки. При этом нужно обновить данные только для тех, у которых поменялись указанные колонки. И, следовательно, только для этих строк изменится время обновления данных.

Но что-то у меня не срабатывает условие проверки обновления только измененных данных и оно обновляет дату обновления для всех найденных строк.

Подскажите, что я сделал не так?

Comment: 1) Выгрузите результат CTE, который используется в обновлении (`not_unique_items `), в таблицу. Убедитесь, что данные соответствуют ожидаемым. 2) Решите вопрос обновления из этой таблицы (UPDATE целевой таблицы с использованием выгруженной). 3) Верните как было и примените сделанные правки.

Comment: Та я вроде так и сделал. Проверил 1 - соответсвуют. 2 - вроде и запрос составил, который должен учитывать значения, которые изменились. Где-то туплю, но не пойму где

Comment: Ну так отбросьте уже CTE и решайте проблему именно обновления. Выложите CREATE TABLE для обеих таблиц, пример значений в них (по 3-4 записи), и требуемый результат. будем смотреть, почему получаемое не соответствует ожиданиям.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e4bc2861763dc17ea77b2d6705372856 - вот. тут для примера данные. и последний запрос мой обновляет постоянно дату обновления в колонке, хотя данные не изменились

Comment: Смотри. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7007f4079d174177f2b3c71b3f527db2 - я добавил вывод того набора записей, который выдаёт CTE для использования при обновлении.  Возьмём твоё условие `WHERE prompt_input_desc != s.description`. Вот есть в исходной таблице в какой-то строке какое-то (любое) значение `prompt_input_desc`. В таблице для обновления есть два разных значения `s.description`, следовательно, по крайней мере для одного из (может, и для обоих) них неравенство - верно. То есть нашлась комбинация, для которой условие выполняется. И строка соответственно будет обновлена.

Comment: Хм, интересный момент. Сам до него не додумался. А какие могут быть здесь варианты решения?

Comment: Самое простое - добавить ещё один CTE, который связывает `not_unique_items` с целевой таблицей, и выбирает из неё только те записи, которые требуют обновления (id целевой таблицы - достаточно), с данными для этого обновления. И уже вот этот CTE используй при обновлении. PS. Я-то постгресс не использую, и мне его синтаксис UPDATE диковат...

Comment: Хорошая подсказка. Спасибо!